# How does memory_order_relaxed work in a branch condition

Tags: c++, concurrency, lock-free

The following code quote from <c++ concurrency in action> Listing 7.13

```cpp
if (ptr->internal_count.fetch_add(-1, std::memory_order_relaxed)==1) {
    ptr->internal_count.load(std::memory_order_acquire);
    // do something
}
```

how `load` with `memory_order_acquire` makes the branch condition work?

Comment: What part of https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/atomic/memory_order is not clear?

Comment: The value it sees will be no earlier in the modification order than the value seen by the `fetch_add`.  It will create a happens-before relationship with the code before a release-store that headed a release-sequence involving the RMWs.  Note that the branch *condition* is decided before we reach the acquire load; it has no effect on which cases result in the if body running.  Just on what they can observe in other objects.